# Why does the WAR file packaged by intellij usually exclude resources directory

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, version

On my workflow, I need to switch git branches frequently, but this made me encountered many times error while I boot up my project after checkout a branch.

I have several modules dependence by my main module, I think their relation is a bit complex, like:

```
mainModule -> A -> X(version 1.0)
mainModule -> B -> X(version 1.2)
mainModule -> X(version 1.8)
```

Once after I checkout a branch, I run my project, if it works, the folder `classes` in my `target` folder include such folder tree like:

```
classes
    --com (java source code)
    --config (config files)
    --static (js code)
    --templates (html page)
```

if it encounters errors, the `classes` directory contains only java source code, file constructure like:

```
classes
    --com (java source code)
```

As you see, three folders are missing, then I receive errors while project boot up because config files are missing which my code needs.

In most situations, my project can work well after delete `target` folders belong to mainModule/A/B/X. But I don't know why this method does not work today.

I think this isn't maven's issue because I can get all files in my manual packaged WAR. I do have solved this problem with change all X dependency to version 1.8(the newest), but my colleague told me that he doesn't want all modules dependence same version because this's not necessary for most situations.

Are there any solutions to solve this problem in IntelliJ? Why does IntelliJ package wrong WAR file?